# Rails 3 App, "following" different types of models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I am building a rails 3 App.  I'll try to describe this application to the best of my ability and as succinctly as possible.

The two main types of models in this app are:

- Users
- Businesses

Then there are two other models:

- Categories
- Subcategories (nested within
  Categories)

How they work together is: the Businesses can have (or belong to, rather) as many categories as they like (and any related subcategories as well).

The user can chose categories to "follow", i.e. they select the categories that they want to show up in their feed, and any businesses that belong to these categories will show up in the feed (same with subcategories)

It's important to note that the categories and subcategories will be dictated by the admins only, the users/businesses can't add/destroy categories, only follow existing ones

My plan for how to implement this was to create a "Following" model with the following attributes

- user_id
- followable_id
- followable_type

of which there would be two "followable_types": user, and business. As you can see this is a not-quite polymorphic model.

Where I am running into trouble is the methods.  For example, how would I create a list of all the businesses that belong to the categories the user is following? It would require some tricky queries and a lot of hackery. This leads me to believe I am approaching the problem from the wrong angle.

Could someone steer me in the right direction? Maybe my architecture needs some work.  Or give me a hint as to how I should be writing my methods.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm confused too.  A user can follow categories and subcategories right? If so then your model is right, but followable type would be "Category" or "Subcategory" and it's a typical polymorphic relationship between a user and a 'followable'.

Comment: Max you have it.  The reason its followable_id and not category_id is because the user can follow subcategories as well. And it's not polymorphic because it categories don't "belong to" any one model (as both businesses and users can HAVE categories).  I apologize if I am being confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the queries you'll be regularly performing I would probably do away with the polymorphism in this case and do something like:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Categories < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :customers
  has_and_belongs_to_many :businesses
end
```

Then the code to perform the query you suggested is pretty simple:

```
Business.joins(:categories).where('categories.id IN (?)', a_user.categories.map(&:id))
```

Comment: thank you! can you explain this portion of the code: a_user.categories.map(&:id)) ? I've seen this before and while I figured it was some kind of shortcut I was never sure what it meant exactly.

Comment: @Ryan Max It calls .id on all of the category objects and returns the result as an array. You can do it with any attribute, for example if you had an array of people and wanted only an array of their names, you could do something like: names = people.map(&:name). It's the equivalent of doing people.map{|p| p.name}

Comment: Awesome, thanks Ant! I ended up going with a has many :through relationship, which is basically the exact same.